# Expanding search bar does not search after closing and reopening it, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an expanding search bar.

I'm using this demo as a base : http://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/qcyGF/

The searchbar works if you open it, write something in the input and then click on the button again

but if you open it, write something in the input, close it by clicking outside of the search bar then open it again; clicking on the button will just close the searchbar again. How can I change the code in a way that if I close and reopen the searchbar it'll search on another click on the button ?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<form class="searchbox">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
    <input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" value="GO">
    <span class="searchbox-icon">GO</span>
</form>
```

Detailed tutorial on [TheCodeBlock](http://thecodeblock.com/realistic-soft-search-box-in-pure-css/)

CSS:

```
    body{
    background:#475f77;
}

.container{
    width:600px;
    margin:50px auto;
}

.searchbox{
    position:relative;
    min-width:50px;
    width:0%;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.3s;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

.searchbox-input{
    top:0;
    right:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    background:#dcddd8;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 55px 0px 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:red;
}
.searchbox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}

.searchbox-icon,
.searchbox-submit{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:22px;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#dcddd8;
    background:#172b3c;
}



.searchbox-open{
    width:100%;
}

.byline{
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:30%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
}
.byline a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #d74b4b;
}
```

Jquery :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
        var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
        var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
        var isOpen = false;
        submitIcon.click(function(){
            if(isOpen == false){
                searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
                inputBox.focus();
                isOpen = true;
            } else {
                searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
                inputBox.focusout();
                isOpen = false;
            }
        });  
         submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
                return false;
            });
        searchBox.mouseup(function(){
                return false;
            });
        $(document).mouseup(function(){
                if(isOpen == true){
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                    submitIcon.click();
                }
            });
    });
        function buttonUp(){
            var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
            inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
            if( inputVal !== 0){
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','none');
            } else {
                $('.searchbox-input').val('');
                $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code base just opens and closes the search bar

```
submitIcon.click(function(){
        if(isOpen == false){
            searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
            inputBox.focus();
            isOpen = true;
        } else {
            searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
            inputBox.focusout();
            isOpen = false;
        }
    });
```

I would change the else (search bar open) code to do the search.